# FbGraph InvalidRequest

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I read the documentation on Facebook Graph API but I m confused with this

[about permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

[about expired access token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/)

my code follow

routes.rb

```
  match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'services#create'
```

services_controller.rb

```
            if service_route == 'facebook'
            omniauth['info']['email'] ? email =  omniauth['info']['email'] : email = ''
            omniauth['info']['name'] ? name =  omniauth['info']['name'] : name = ''
            omniauth['uid'] ?  uid =  omniauth['uid'] : uid = ''
            omniauth['provider'] ? provider =  omniauth['provider'] : provider = ''
            omniauth['credentials']['token'] ? session['fb_access_token'] =  omniauth['credentials']['token'] : session['fb_access_token'] = ''
```

student.rb

```
 def facebook
    @fb_user ||= FbGraph::User.me(self.services.find_by_provider('facebook').token)
 end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
    def create

    @article = current_student.articles.new(params[:article])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @article.save
            format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Το άρθρο δημιουργήθηκε επιτυχώς.') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }


            current_student.facebook.feed!(
                :message => 'Hello, Facebook!',
                :name => 'My Rails 3 App with Omniauth, Devise and FB_graph')
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "services", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "uname"
    t.string   "uemail"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "token
```

and finaly the problem when create articles i take this

```
   FbGraph::InvalidRequest in ArticlesController#create

   OAuthException :: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code is right. Only missing in

service.rb

```
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :uname, :uemail, :token
```

and everything is Okay